# App held for ransom by Android. Can not uninstall: Privilege denied

Tags: uninstallation

I have downloaded "Root Swapper Extended Memory" from the Google Play Store, and now I am denied the privilege to uninstall this app. More detail about denied privilege:

• Cannot Uninstall
• Cannot move to card
• Cannot Force Stop
• Cannot Clear Cache

Comment: Could you post a screenshot which shows what you describe as "denied privilege"?

Comment: Are you speaking of [this app](http://www.appbrain.com/app/root-swapper-extend-memory/com.Root_Swapper_Extend_Memory_20510)? AppBrain lists it as possible spam/malware (searching for the app name there, you'll see it's "masked" in the result set). Though the permissions shown don't indicate it: Have you checked whether the app might have registered with the "device manager"? If so, you'd need to first unlist it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to Settings > Security > Device Administrators do you see the app listed there?

If so uncheck the checkbox and you should be able to un-install the app (using the play store app or from the application manager)